# Printing the Float Numbers in Python for Cordinate System

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, floating-point

I am trying to write a method that generates and returns n random points in a 2-dimensional space given the width and height in Python I coded an algorithm but I want to recieve float points in the system.
Here my code is:

```
import random    

npoints = int(input("Type the npoints:"))
width = int(input("Enter the Width you want:"))
height = int (input("Enter the Height you want:"))


allpoints = [(a,b) for a in range(width) for b in range(height)]
sample = random.sample(allpoints, npoints)

print(sample)

Output is:

Type the npoints:4
Enter the Width you want:10
Enter the Height you want:8
[(8, 7), (3, 3), (7, 7), (9, 0)]
```

How can I print them as float. For example: (8.75 , 6.31)

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to take `float` as input. For `height` & `width` replace the `int()` with `float()`.

Now, you can't generate all point within the box defined by these any more since floating points can have arbitrary precision (theoretically).

So you need a way to generate the coordinates separately. A random y-coordinate between 0 & `height` can be generated by:

```
<random number between 0 to 1> * height
```

Similarly for the width. And you can use `random.random()` to get the random number between 0 to 1.

Full code:

```
import random

npoints = int(input("Type the npoints:"))
width = float(input("Enter the Width you want:"))
height = float(input("Enter the Height you want:"))

sample = []
for _ in range(npoints):
    sample.append((width * random.random(), height * random.random()))

print(sample)
```

Output:

```
Type the npoints:3
Enter the Width you want:2.5
Enter the Height you want:3.5
[(0.7136697226350142, 1.3640823010874898), (2.4598008083240517, 1.691902371689177), (1.955991673900633, 2.730363157986461)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `a` and `b` to `float`:

```
import random    

npoints = int(input("Type the npoints:"))
width = int(input("Enter the Width you want:"))
height = int (input("Enter the Height you want:"))

# HERE ---------v--------v
allpoints = [(float(a),float(b)) for a in range(width) for b in range(height)]
sample = random.sample(allpoints, npoints)

print(sample)
```

Output:

```
Type the npoints:4
Enter the Width you want:10
Enter the Height you want:8
[(1.0, 0.0), (8.0, 7.0), (5.0, 1.0), (2.0, 5.0)]
```

**Update**

> I want float but your solve is printing only like this: 2.0 5.0
> How can we print like this: 5.56 2.75 ?

Print with 2 decimals:

```
>>> print(*[f"({w:.2f}, {h:.2f})" for w, h in sample], sep=', ')
(1.00, 0.00), (8.00, 7.00), (5.00, 1.00), (2.00, 5.00)
```

Comment: Thanks bro but its only turns the int to float. How can I get like 5,56 ,  10,35 etc. ?

Comment: You don't want float but string, that's right?

Comment: No bro I want float but your solve is printing only like this: 2.0 5.0    How can we print like this: 5.56   2.75 ?

Comment: Yeah bro thanks a lot.